# TouchId should invalidate the fingerprints which have added/updated after the app installation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, fingerprint, touch-id

We have the following requirement in our app.

We should restrict the user to login, if user **adds/updates** any finger print after the app installation.

Comment: hi, did you find the solution? if you can you please share that.

Answer (score 3):

If your app saves some credential to the keychain and then uses TouchID to access that saved credential, you can specify `kSecAccessControlTouchIDCurrentSet` on the access control for the keychain item.  Then, if the enrolled fingerprint set is changed (fingerprints added or deleted), access will be denied to the keychain item.

Answer (score 1):

**From iOS 9,** LAContext class supports **evaluatedPolicyDomainState** which help developers to identify in fingerprint data updates like fingers were removed or added.

So for in your case we can do like these:

- Store user fingerprint data in application while open first time.
- Every time when user try to access app fetch current device fingerprint data & compare with last stored data. If we found any change than restrict user.